# One permanency for multiple spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

> This spell makes the duration of certain other spell**s** permanent. You first cast the desired spell and then follow it with the [permanency](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/permanency) spell.

What if you're under the influence of multiple spells that could potentially be made permanent and own enough diamond dust for the making-permanent of all of them? Would one casting of permanency be enough?

If not, how would it decide which of the spells becomes permanent?

Comment: ***"If not, how would it decide which of the spells becomes permanent?"*** -- the wording is sloppy, but you should probably treat it as *target: one spell* rather than *target: see below*.

Answer (score 7):

In its normal use, it's one *permanency* per spell to be made permanent. The only time you get a "bulk discount" on permanency is when it's part of the magic item creation process, when one *permanency* might be how multiple enchantments are bound into the item. For plain old spells on yourself, there's no bulk discount.

Comment: Do you have a source for the bulk discount on items?

Comment: @Julix He's talking about hypothetical items that require *permanency* to craft, I believe. The rules for magic-item-creation state that you must cast each spell once as a part of the creation process. But I really doubt that *permanency* is ever actually used in the creation of any item, since it would be very clear what, if any, money it costs to cast for the purposes of making the item.